# PHP - Detect the character encoding of the file system

Tags: php

How to detect the character encoding of the file system that your script is currently running on whether it is on Windows or Linux?

I have a form in which the user will upload a file and give it a name. once uploaded and moved to the desired destination, files that have names like:

```
wéîrd nàmès
```

will be saved with names like:

```
wÃ©Ã®r nÃ mÃ¨s
```

I tried `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding` but I couldn't find out which character encoding to use.

I don't want to detect the character encoding of the file itself. I want to detect the character encoding which I will uses to save the file.

This is the php used to upload files:

```
mkdir ($webdir . '/files/location/' . $doc_name . '/');

if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['docx_file']['tmp_name'], $webdir . '/files/location/' . $doc_name . '/' . $doc_name . '.docx')){
    echo 'docx upload failed miserably..';
    rmdir($webdir . '/files/location/' . $doc_name . '/');
}else{
    echo 'docx upload completed successfully!';
}
```

Let's say that the file name is **dédé**

First I create the folder `$webdir . '/files/location/dédé'`

Then I move the uploaded file to `$webdir . '/files/location/dédé/dédé.docx'`

If an error occurs while moving the file (which doesn't happen) I delete the folder that I recently created.

Everything goes well except for the folder and file names which will be saved as **dÃ©dÃ©** . Both of them.

I tried this before running the above script:

```
echo $doc_name . "\r\n";
echo (mb_detect_encoding($doc_name)) . "\r\n";
```

And it gave me this result:

```
dédé
UTF-8
docx upload completed successfully!
```

**EDIT**

I added this before running the above script:

```
echo $doc_name . "\r\n";
echo (mb_detect_encoding($doc_name)) . "\r\n";

$doc_name =  (mb_convert_encoding($doc_name, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII'));

echo $doc_name . "\r\n";
echo (mb_detect_encoding($doc_name)) . "\r\n";
```

`$doc_name` have **dédé** inside it and is encoded in **UTF-8**.

First it shows this:

```
dédé
UTF-8
```

Then I use `mb_convert_encoding` to convert it from **ASCII** to **UTF-8** and it shows this:

```
dÃ©dÃ©
UTF-8
```

Which is exactly the file names used instead of **dédé**

Is it possible that `mkdir` and `move_uploaded_file` are automatically converting the strings from **ASCII** to **UTF-8** before saving? Is it possible that I have run some function that makes this possible? I have a really long script running before this one and I can't really put it all here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I used **mb_detect_encoding** on some of the files on my server and i found out that some of them with normal names are encoded in **ASCII** while the others with names containing characters like **é** are encoded in **UTF-8**. The strings I pass to the function **move_uploaded_file** are encoded in UTF-8, is the problem comming from the function?

Comment: @Fred-ii- None of those are relevant here. Saving non-ASCII file names if indeed messy, advising on "UTF-8 all the way" is not helpful. Fi Ras, I'd rather suggest you use randomly generated, meaningless names for the files themselves (e.g. a UUID or a hash of the contents) and save the Unicode file name in a database as meta data; if that's a possibility.

Comment: I urge you not to store files using the name the user gives.  Either keep that in meta-data, or base64_encode the name.

Comment: Ok @deceze I have deleted "all" my comments to the OP, including the one about "mkdir" and "rmdir".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after so much time I figured that my script does something like this before saving folders and file's names :

```
$doc_name = mb_convert_encoding($doc_name, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

The name is already encoded in **UTF-8** but for some unkown reason my script still tries to encode the name from **ISO-8859-1** to **UTF-8** wich results in changing strings like **dédé** to **dÃ©dÃ©**.

So I tried to fixe it by encoding the name from **UTF-8** to **ISO-8859-1** by using :

```
$doc_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $doc_name);
```

And I thought my script will return it to **UTF-8** automatically and I got this :

```
Original: dédé ===> Encoded in ISO-8859-1: d�d� ===> Encoded to UTF-8: dédé
```

And it worked.

**mkdir()**,

**rmdir()**,

**is_dir()**,

**move_uploaded_files()**,

**file_exists()**,

**rename()**..

All of them need the strings to be encoded in **ISO-8859-1**.<s>, however, **is_dir()** works with **UTF-8**</s>

Comment: And now try to answer the question how to name a file "今月商品.xls". Great if ISO-8859 works *for you*, but it's unfortunately not a generic solution to use any and all possible file names.